# How to Join tables flat with fixed params with Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have datesets in spark with certain columns. I want to join those dataset flat by keeping some columns as reference(id, date, name).

DATASET 1: (d1)

| id | date | name | val1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15-06-2022 | n1 | 10 |
| 2 | 15-06-2022 | n1 | 12 |
| 3 | 15-06-2022 | n1 | 24 |
| 4 | 16-09-2021 | n2 | 27 |

DATASET 1: (d2)

| id | date | name | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15-06-2022 | n1 | 15 |
| 1 | 12-06-2021 | n1 | 123 |
| 2 | 15-06-2022 | n2 | 56 |
| 15 | 21-03-2022 | n1 | 43 |
| 4 | 16-09-2021 | n2 | 65 |

Output

| id | date | name | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15-06-2022 | n1 | 10 | 15 |
| 1 | 12-06-2021 | n1 | 0 | 123 |
| 2 | 15-06-2022 | n1 | 12 | 0 |
| 2 | 15-06-2022 | n2 | 0 | 56 |
| 3 | 15-06-2022 | n1 | 24 | 0 |
| 4 | 16-09-2021 | n2 | 27 | 65 |
| 15 | 21-03-2022 | n1 | 0 | 43 |

I will make the id, data, name columns fixed, If all three are same then I will do flat join, else create new row with the values being 0 incase of null

Please help me with appropriate sql or dataset logic in spark to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `full outer join` based on `Id,date,name` to Result all data of two data sets if matching Records are there it will join based on Id,date,name. use `coalesce` to avoid null's

```
    declare @Datset1 table (
    Id int,
    date varchar(120),
    name varchar(10),
    val1 int
    );

    insert into @Datset1
    values(1,'15-06-2022','n1',10),
    (2,'15-06-2022','n1',12),
    (3,'15-06-2022','n1',24),
    (4,'16-09-2021','n2',27);


    declare @Datset2 table (
    Id int,
    date varchar(120),
    name varchar(10),
    val2 int
    );
    insert into @Datset2
    values(1    ,'15-06-2022','n1', 15),
    (1  ,'12-06-2021','n1', 123),
    (2  ,'15-06-2022','n2', 56),
    (15 ,'21-03-2022','n1', 43),
    (4  ,'16-09-2021','n2', 65);

    select coalesce(dt1.Id,dt2.Id) as Id,
    coalesce(dt1.date,dt2.date) as date,
    coalesce(dt1.name,dt2.name) as name,
    coalesce(dt1.val1,0) as val1,
    coalesce(dt2.val2,0) as val2
    from @Datset1 dt1 full outer join @Datset2 dt2 on dt1.Id=dt2.Id and dt1.date=dt2.date and dt1.name=dt2.name;
```

Output will be as follows

| Id | date | name | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15-06-2022 | n1 | 10 | 15 |
| 2 | 15-06-2022 | n1 | 12 | 0 |
| 3 | 15-06-2022 | n1 | 24 | 0 |
| 4 | 16-09-2021 | n2 | 27 | 65 |
| 1 | 12-06-2021 | n1 | 0 | 123 |
| 2 | 15-06-2022 | n2 | 0 | 56 |
| 15 | 21-03-2022 | n1 | 0 | 43 |